# Como renderizar um json com o adaptador json_api usando Rails Serializer?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

Opa, eu gostaria de renderizar um json usando o padrão json_api (http://jsonapi.org/) usando o Rails Serializer(https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers).

No meu controler estou renderizando algo semelhante a isso:

```
render json: {'user': {name: 'Peter' }}
```

Porém, quando eu renderizo esse JSON, ele não está saindo no formato json_api.

Em outros Controllers/Models os serializers estão funcionando corretamente, uma vez que estão utilizando o ActiveRecord, porém nesse caso eu não consigo passar um ActiveRecord  e gostaria de manter os outputs da minha api padronizados.

** Obs: Não consigo passar o ActiveRecord nesse controler pois ele não possui uma tabela.

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em português. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Ops, traduzido.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você renderiza no formato `json` você pode passar alguns parâmetros opcionais como o serializer do seu usuário assim como o seu adaptador:

```
def index
  render json: @users, serializer: UserSerializer, adapter: :json_api
end
```

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/serializers.md

Comment: Tentei aqui, desta maneira não da certo. Ele continua renderizando somente o JSON, sem a estrutura do json_api

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi a parte do "Em outros Controllers/Models os serializers estão funcionando corretamente, uma vez que estão utilizando o ActiveRecord".

Esses outros models já estão serializados? Se sim vc já deveria ver uma diferença no response para esses models. Poste o response para esses casos pra gente dar uma olhada.

O modelo padrão do Rails para renderizar JSON é a classe `ActiveSupport::JSON` e não a `ActiveRecord`.

Mas por padrão pra configurar o AMS(ActiveModelSerializers) com a especificação JSON:API vc precisa:

- Adicionar a gem do AMS no sem Gemfile `gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0'`
- Rodar um `bundle install`
- Criar um arquivo em **PASTA_DO_PROJETO/config/initializers/ams.rb**(pode ser qualquer nome invés de ams.rb) e adicionar a seguinte linha: `ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api # Default: :attributes`. Essa linha vai dizer ao AMS para fazer user da especificação JSON:API
- Criar o *Serializer* para os models escolhidos com o comando `rails g serializer MODEL_NAME`.

O método SHOW do seu **users_controller.rb** pode ser algo como:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  ...
  ...
  # GET /users/1
  def show
    render json: @user
  end
  ...
  ...
  private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
   def set_user
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
   end

   def user_params
     ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(params)
   end
end
```

E autorizar os atributos no ser **user_serializer.rb** e colocar configurações desejadas:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email, :outro_atributo

  belongs_to :alguma_associação
  has_many :outra_associação
  has_one :alguma_outra_associação
end
```

Espero ter ajudado.